# Angular Material md-grid-list?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How much columns does maintain `md-grid-list` in Angular 2?

Can I set, for example:

```
<md-grid-list cols="20" rowHeight="5">
</md-grid-list>

Or cols="100"
```

Is there limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the limit is based on your screen size. You can use the flex-layout library from the angular team to adjust the numbers of cols. Look at this article.

http://brianflove.com/2017/05/03/responsive-angular/